# In an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, how can I save the post data in the where their session times out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, post, timeout

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.  The site involves people writing lengthy responses using a textarea in a web form.  Occasionally, users are complaining that they are getting redirected to the log in form after they post their data.  I am not sure exactly why they are getting logged out because the users do not typically provide enough information on their errors.  I believe it is due either to a session time out or the application has been restarted for some reason.  This is on a shared web hosting site and it does not have its own app pool.

In any case, regardless of the reason, I would like to capture that post data and save it to a db or text file.  How can I get the post data and save it while the controller redirects the user to the login screen.

I know the long term plan would be to identify why the timeout is occurring.  But for now I want to be able to grab the post data and recover it at a later time.

Comment: I would recommend increasing session timeout, if not you can do something on session_End in your global.asax

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to avoid timeouts, I would recommend using client-side heartbeat solution (like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Heartbeat)

Second, assuming that you are using forms authentication, in order to save posted data, when Forms Authorization Module is redirecting your users, you will need to intercept redirects in `EndRequest` HttpApplication event handler in Global.asax or your own module.

The way to intercept those requests is not that straightforward, since on "EndRequest" pipeline step you will see 302 HTTP status code (redirect instruction), not 401 (Unauthorized error). So you may check if request is not authenticated (`HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`) and request is redirected - in this case you may save what you see in the request.

Otherwise you would need to disable forms authentication and use some solution, which is closer to ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

one solution can be to put a javasscript timer which keeps on hitting the server after specified interval to keep session alive until u figure out the cause of session time out (only i its the session timeout problem)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the session from timing out, you can add a hidden iframe on the page. For example, create a new page called KeepSessionAlive and do this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

where content = seconds.
I don't know about MVC 3, but the way you can get and store the post values is to catch them before redirecting the user to the Login page.